# How to prove this formula for surface integrals?

Tags: surface-integrals

Let $f(x)$ be a continuous function on $\mathbb{R}$. Prove
$$\iint\limits_{S}f(x+y+z)dS=2\pi\int_{-1}^{1}f(\sqrt{3}\xi) d\xi$$
where S is $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$.
I have already noticed that $\iint\limits_{S}f(x+y+z)dS=\iint\limits_{S}f(x+y+z)\cdot \frac{-1}{z}dx\wedge dy$, then I tried to let $$\left\{\begin{matrix}
  x=&\cos{\varphi} \cdot \cos{\phi} \\
  y=&\cos{\varphi} \cdot \sin{\phi}  \\
  z=&\sin{\varphi}
\end{matrix}\right.$$
so the formula turns into $\iint\limits_{\varphi\in[0,2\pi],\phi\in[-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}]}f(\cos{\varphi} \cdot \cos{\phi}+\cos{\varphi} \cdot \sin{\phi}+\sin{\varphi})\cdot \cos {\varphi}d\varphi d\phi$ But then I was stucked at here. I want to use Fubini Theorem but  I can't separate $\cos{\varphi}$ out of the formula. How can I do next ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically we are going to use spherical coordinates with the $z$-axis along the line $\{t(1,1,1):t\in\mathbb{R}\}$.

We first apply the rotation of $45^{\circ}$ around $z$-axis:
$$\begin{cases}
x=\frac{x'+y'}{\sqrt{2}}\\
y=\frac{x'-y'}{\sqrt{2}}\\
z=z'
\end{cases}.$$
Hence
$$I:=\iint\limits_{S}f(x+y+z)dS=\iint\limits_{S}f(\sqrt{2}x'+z')dS.$$
Then we apply the rotation of $\alpha^{\circ}$ around $y'$-axis where $\alpha^{\circ}$ is the angle between the vector $(1,1,1)$ and the plane $z=0$ (note that $\cos(\alpha^{\circ})=\frac{(1,1,1)}{\sqrt{3}}\cdot(0,1,0)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$):
$$\begin{cases}
x'=\frac{x''+\sqrt{2}z''}{\sqrt{3}}\\
y'=y''\\z'=\frac{-\sqrt{2}x''+z''}{\sqrt{3}}
\end{cases}.$$ Hence
$$I=\iint\limits_{S}f\Big(\sqrt{2}\Big(\frac{x''+\sqrt{2}z''}{\sqrt{3}}\Big)+\Big(\frac{-\sqrt{2}x''+z''}{\sqrt{3}}\Big)\Big)dS
=\iint\limits_{S}f(\sqrt{3}z'')dS.$$
Note that $S$ is invariant with respect of those two rotations.

Finally we use spherical coordinates with the *new* $z''$-axis :
$$I=\iint\limits_{S}f(\sqrt{3}z'')dS=\int_{\theta=0}^{2\pi}\int_{\phi=-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}f(\sqrt{3}\sin(\phi))\cos(\phi)d\theta d\phi=2\pi\int_{-1}^{1}f(\sqrt{3}\xi) d\xi$$
where $\xi=\sin(\phi)$.

Comment: Thanks！How could you find these rotations 

Comment: @ZTR05 See my edit!